Celery worker stops consuming tasks after some minutes for failed sync
On my django project I'm experiencing an issue with celery and redis as messages broker.
Current versions: 
celery==5.3.6
redis==5.0.8

The problem can be described with this log:
2024-09-15 14:31:05  -------------- celery@5d4164b0472c v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
2024-09-15 14:31:05 --- ***** ----- 
2024-09-15 14:31:05 -- ******* ---- Linux-6.10.0-linuxkit-aarch64-with-glibc2.31 2024-09-15 12:31:05
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - *** --- * --- 
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - ** ---------- [config]
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - ** ---------- .> app:         core:0xffff8a65b550
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://:**@redis-12345.c123.eu-west-3-1.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com:00000//
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://:**@redis-12345.c123.eu-west-3-1.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com:00000/
2024-09-15 14:31:05 - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 11 (solo)
2024-09-15 14:31:05 -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
2024-09-15 14:31:05 --- ***** ----- 
2024-09-15 14:31:05  -------------- [queues]
2024-09-15 14:31:05                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
2024-09-15 14:31:05                 .> celery:1         exchange=celery:1(direct) key=celery:1
2024-09-15 14:31:05                 .> celery:2         exchange=celery:2(direct) key=celery:2
2024-09-15 14:31:05                 .> celery:3         exchange=celery:3(direct) key=celery:3
2024-09-15 14:31:05 
2024-09-15 14:31:05 [tasks]
2024-09-15 14:31:05   . apps.data_integration.tasks.celery_dataddo_process
2024-09-15 14:31:05   . apps.incrementality_experiment.tasks.geolift_market_match_task
2024-09-15 14:31:05 
2024-09-15 14:31:05 [2024-09-15 12:31:05,926: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@redis-12345.c123.eu-west-3-1.ec2.redns.redis-cloud.com:00000//
2024-09-15 14:31:06 [2024-09-15 12:31:06,739: INFO/MainProcess] celery@5d4164b0472c ready.
2024-09-15 14:38:16 [2024-09-15 12:38:16,078: INFO/MainProcess] sync with celery@03ffef68e38c
2024-09-15 14:38:16 [2024-09-15 12:38:16,621: ERROR/MainProcess] Control command error: ValueError('not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)')
2024-09-15 14:38:16 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/celery/worker/pidbox.py", line 44, in on_message
2024-09-15 14:38:16     self.node.handle_message(body, message)
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 143, in handle_message
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return self.dispatch(**body)
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 110, in dispatch
2024-09-15 14:38:16     self.reply({self.hostname: reply},
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 147, in reply
2024-09-15 14:38:16     self.mailbox._publish_reply(data, exchange, routing_key, ticket,
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 277, in _publish_reply
2024-09-15 14:38:16     producer.publish(
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 186, in publish
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return _publish(
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/connection.py", line 556, in _ensured
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return fun(*args, **kwargs)
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 208, in _publish
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return channel.basic_publish(
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 610, in basic_publish
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return self.typeof(exchange).deliver(
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 74, in deliver
2024-09-15 14:38:16     for queue in _lookup(exchange, routing_key):
2024-09-15 14:38:16                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/base.py", line 721, in _lookup
2024-09-15 14:38:16     R = self.typeof(exchange).lookup(
2024-09-15 14:38:16         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 66, in lookup
2024-09-15 14:38:16     return {
2024-09-15 14:38:16            ^
2024-09-15 14:38:16   File "/home/pippo/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/kombu/transport/virtual/exchange.py", line 67, in <setcomp>
2024-09-15 14:38:16     queue for rkey, _, queue in table
2024-09-15 14:38:16               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2024-09-15 14:38:16 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

This is happening both in docker and in the aws system when I deploy. Right after the deployment or the compose of the container, if I give the system tasks to run it's elaborating them perfectly, but if I leave it unused for a couple of minutes its breaking as the log says.
I currently using this configuration on docker-compose:
celery:
    <<: *app
    command: celery -A core worker --without-mingle --without-gossip --without-heartbeat --pool=solo -l info -Q celery,celery:1,celery:2,celery:3
    ports:
        - 5554:5554
    depends_on:
        - db
        - redis

and this configuration on celery.py:
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

# Initialize Celery application.
app = Celery('core')

# Load task-related settings from the Django project settings using the 'CELERY' namespace.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Ensure broker connection retries on startup for Celery 6.0 and above.
app.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True

# Broker transport options for message priority and task routing strategy.
app.conf.broker_transport_options = {
    'priority_steps': list(range(10)),
    'sep': ':',
    'queue_order_strategy': 'priority',
}

# Limit task prefetching to one task at a time to balance worker load.
app.conf.worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1

app.conf.task_soft_time_limit = 1200  # 20 minutes
app.conf.task_time_limit = 1500       # 25 minutes, hard limit

app.conf.broker_heartbeat = 30  # Increase Redis heartbeat check interval
app.conf.broker_connection_timeout = 10  # Time in seconds to wait for connection
app.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True  # Ensure retries

app.conf.task_acks_late = True  # Acknowledge task only after completion
app.conf.task_reject_on_worker_lost = True  # Reject task if worker is lost
app.conf.task_default_retry_delay = 300  # Retry after 5 minutes
app.conf.task_max_retries = 5  # Max retries for failed tasks

# Automatically discover tasks from installed apps (tasks.py).
app.autodiscover_tasks()


Can you please show your task that you are running? I can't deduce what is happening from the traceback, and it doesn't seem this way based on your post, but I'd like to ensure you aren't hitting an actual task error you wrote, before trying to look at why a package isn't working correctly. I'd like to see this task: apps.incrementality_experiment.tasks.geolift_market_match_task

I actually doesn't matter if I launch a task or I don't. After some minutes it will result with that error if I don't launch a task from the application.
I can show you how I've defined this task:
@shared_task(bind=True, max_retries=3, acks_late=True, queue='celery:1')
def geolift_market_match_task(self, geo_lift_id, channel_contribution=None, model_cpic=None)
